# Playing a sound on tap on a key on custom number pad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uidevice

I am creating and putting a custom number bar on top of regular keypad. Now, when I tap on the keys in the numberpad, I want the regular keyboard sound to play. I am using the below code in the button pressed delegate. Log statement prints but there is no sound on my device. A tap on any key on the regular keypad play the sound. Do I need to enable something?

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)iSender {
    NSLog(@"Button is pressed");
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the docs:

> Use this method to play the standard system keyboard click in response
>   to a user tapping in a custom input or keyboard accessory view. A
>   click plays only if the user has enabled keyboard clicks in Settings >
>   Sounds, and only if the input view is itself enabled and visible.
>
> To enable a custom input or accessory view for input clicks, perform
>   the following two steps:
>
> Adopt the UIInputViewAudioFeedback protocol in your input view class.
>   Implement the enableInputClicksWhenVisible delegate method to return
>   YES.

Sounds like that method is not useful as a general-purpose "play a click" method. It's tightly coupled to input views.